# django: display UpdateView in language defined by the object

Tags: django, django-models, translation, modelform

I have a django project where I would like to display an `UpdateView` of a `ModelForm` in the language which is defined by the model itself. I would like to avoid using i18n patterns in the URL.

The object to be displayed is identified via an UUID provided in the URL of the form
`http://name.tld/submit/55dbf53c-9364-4938-873f-6abad2e4ed45`

I have:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    unique_id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, 
        editable=False, 
        unique=True,
        verbose_name=_("UUID Field")
    )
    language = models.CharField(
        default = "en",
        max_length=7,
        choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
        verbose_name=_("Selected language")
    )
```

ModelForm:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      localized_fields = '__all__'
      fields = '__all__'
```

UpdateView:

```
class MyModelUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name_suffix = '_form'

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        # get the uuid and find the corresponding object
        obj = MyModel.objects.filter(unique_id=self.kwargs.get('uuid')).first()
        if not obj or obj.is_answered:
            raise Http404("Page not found")
        else:
            translation.activate(obj.language)
            return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('submit-success')
```

Template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans alert %}
<h2>{% trans "My great translated UpdateView" %}</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% form %}
</form>
```

However, despite providing the translated strings in the PO files (created using `django-admin makemessages` and `django-admin compilemessages` the page always shows up in English (my browser language, that is).

What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind, the code works exactly as expected, the only thing missing was to actually correctly configure the `LOCALE_PATHS` variabe in the project settings. Django's `makemessages` and `compilemessages` commands work without this setting and still find the appropriate language files, but the files are then not found by the middleware.